# How to draw small button inside big button in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uikeyboard

I made a button already. When I click it, it becomes big but letter is not in good position. I want to put another button inside the big button. How can I do this ?

Comment: You could probably just add it as another subview but why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: could you give some example codes ?

Comment: This is the feedback from my company !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wish to add a second button as a subview of the first button, you can use this:

```
UIButton *mySmallButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[mySmallButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[myBigButton addSubview:mySmallButton];
```

However, if you're just looking to modify the text size/alignment of the first button once it has grown you can use these:

```
[[myBigButton titleLabel] setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[[myBigButton titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24]];
```

Comment: Can I ask 1 more ? If I don't to put title on big button, how can I put title on small button ?

Comment: I try to put title on small button, but fail !

Comment: @smallgirl `[mySmallButton setTitle:@"some title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`